# Nginx: multiple locations on same server

Tags: nginx

This is my `nginx conf` file.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location /some/directory {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8998;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8999;
    }
}
```

For some reason `example.com` and `example2.com` are working, but `example.com/some/directory` is not.

- `localhost:9000` & `localhost:8999`: are [harp.js](https://harpjs.com/) sites, they have they own routing, and work properly, both locally and on the proxy-ed domains (example.com & example2.com).
- `localhost:8998`: is a golang api, it works locally and also if I access `example.com:8998` or `example2.com:8998`.

Is there something wrong with the conf?

*EDIT*: added more info to the question.

Comment: How does the working request for `example.com:8998` look like?

Comment: What do you mean how it looks like? It works properly.

Comment: In your configuration nginx requests `http://localhost:8998/some/directory`. Do you test the same request?

Comment: I'll add more information to the question to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
    }

    location /some/directory {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8998/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8999/;
    }
}
```

Try this, adding the last **/** in the proxy_pass's should work.